# Iterate through True Bits of Binary Number (Fast)

Tags: python, performance, math, binary

So I'm trying to make a function in Python to return all of the powers of two used in the binary of a number.

For example: 123 in binary is 1111011. I want my function to return the powers of two corresponding to the True bits of 123 (1, 2, 8, 16, 32 and 64) as fast as possible.

Right now the best I've found is:

```
def true_bits(num):
    while num:
        temp = num & -num
        num -= temp
        yield temp
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I tried with numpy (and python loop), it's slower

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark sure, I added an answer

Comment: I'm quite impressed with the code you have in the question already.  The `x&-x` trick is great for skipping over all the zero bits automatically.  I think `temp_num` is redundant, you could have used `num` directly, but I don't think it affects the timing.  That's going to be hard to top.

Comment: How big are your numbers, and what do you need this for?

Comment: @MarkRansom Whether it can be topped depends on what they're doing. If they only have small numbers, lookup-tables could beat it. If they have large numbers, splitting them might beat it. And I suspect the real improvement would come from not doing this at all.

Comment: @KellyBundy this is for a chess program that uses bitboards to represent pieces, so the numbers will be between 0 and 2^64 - 1.

Comment: How many of the 64 bits are true, on average?

Comment: @KellyBundy well again, it’s chess, so somewhere between 32 (the maximum number of possible pieces on a board) and 3 (two kings is an immediate draw)

Comment: @KellyBundy I considered a combination of splitting with a lookup table, but my intuition says it wouldn't be faster.  Lookup tables aren't very cache friendly, and a modern processor can do a lot of operations in the time it takes to do a single lookup.

Comment: @MarkRansom We're talking about Python, though. I [benchmarked](https://tio.run/##RY/dCsIwDEbv8xS5si3MCzcUEfYkY8jUTgv2hy5DfPratOByEzj5etKEL728684hpjRHb5GM1YbQ2OAjYdRBTwSwaFoD9iiEgLf/3HKix4zeWg5utbjDPbfZR@RuHMbJPbVsjyc1KmDW46HtgAVw9w@9ZDAA5hKbQDSV1BVsHjMaAVh83bSdupQgY5bxpEgr5uIPWuNkvUDytMFyhlL/UIjGkaSmPK64IpXSDw) `num & -num` at 86 ns and `lowbit[num]` at 32 ns.

Comment: @Ghull Well, wasn't clear what the number represents. I'll give it a shot now. You might want to include this information in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Some (non-faster) alternatives:

Using `numpy` and assuming 8bits unsigned integers:

```
import numpy as np
def numpy_bits(num):
    bits = np.unpackbits(np.uint8(num), bitorder='little')
    return 2**np.arange(8)[bits.astype(bool)]

numpy_bits(123)
# array([ 1,  2,  8, 16, 32, 64])
# 6.8 µs ± 293 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Using a python loop (decreasing bit order):

```
def python_bits(num):
    for i in range(7,-1,-1):
        if num >= (x:=2**i):
            yield x
            num -= x

list(python_bits(123))
# [64, 32, 16, 8, 2, 1]
# 2.26 µs ± 61.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

OP's approach:

```
list(true_bits(123))
# [1, 2, 8, 16, 32, 64]
# 1.14 µs ± 37.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Comment: I assume *"OP's true_bits(123)"* means you timed `list(true_bits(123))`

Comment: @Stef yes of course (I didn't time the generator :p), updated for clarity

Comment: Taking 2 to a power is never going to be faster than simple bit manipulation.

Comment: @MarkRansom I never said so, I think OP's approach is great ;) I only provided the answer following a (now-deleted) request in comment (initially suggesting to use the powers of 2)

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark with a bunch of random 64-bit numbers with 24 true bits (based on what you said in the comments):

```
47.7 ms  true_bits_original
16.0 ms  true_bits_Kelly

45.6 ms  true_bits_original
15.7 ms  true_bits_Kelly

47.4 ms  true_bits_original
16.3 ms  true_bits_Kelly
```

I'm using eight lookup-tables, each responsible for eight of the bits. Full code with benchmark ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZXBjqMwDIbvPIWl1eyEDlNBS5mqGuayxz3usaoQbU0bCQIbgnaq1T57N04y0HZG4lAOVNi/v9iO5TYndazFfNnI85kLhVJACn9nkwlfAb2hqCVw4AJkLg7Iktj/Nz2g8lS@LTHU4jXzN96NaumvPNCPEz2RarLlqg3AHsKI7fuGTnYKteLNQFZdUyKzn741R4PZvB1NI@D1FZY9kHjE/eoEh5rdj4ocan4/auZQ8f2ouUMt7kfFDpXcj1o41Mv9qMT3vD0WoGSHGXmyn1iWJya6ys2dRNXpSd4dcy7cAK21F75D@F4Um8CIrh57n2tiwNsb5TGinfXaKBkVz3vxLB4Vx714PhsVL3pxHI6Kk0E8XuDL2mkXyeZTw2vJD1zk5UXP/xx5iaC/Vz1QYdXo67adf9Y/vYdMz6kR9LYTx3JvTV7RiV1Lk/LpxOD22j2PV00tFSheIVdeIesKuB4qVdelHhrrlNhgrgI7ElajV9WepFagdxoZ7JJq80rPppXt6rLEneK16GF7/N2h532DH7WU2iewbc0KzIYVGIVh6DpDxaaXB9AWNR58b3S4dpa8VcwUvQ43pqlWQFAyE9e4h@bmbatrHCJtFKSpo1J@vxrE/W1m8yEtavG67Sp2vept@azf@AGNrX81J19UG@r/gZGcaYhkJ5i/uoIdUFAmVd6YSgKT2vV5O93@rsIPmbmBwAQG7m5ZeJOi0bCPwADCwU0tr2g1mJGZOoDOzBy9RZlGF7BG6iXFHh/iaVSA7tkjPABTMIFI79rA1DjNMpFXmGU2ykb45/N/)):

```
intern = {2**i: 2**i for i in range(64)}.get
table0 = [()]
for i in range(8):
    table0 += [(*bits, intern(2**i)) for bits in table0]
table0 = tuple(table0)
table1 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table0)
table2 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table1)
table3 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table2)
table4 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table3)
table5 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table4)
table6 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table5)
table7 = tuple(tuple(intern(bit << 8) for bit in bits) for bits in table6)

def true_bits_Kelly(num):
    return chain(table0[num & 0xff],
                 table1[(num >> 8) & 0xff],
                 table2[(num >> 16) & 0xff],
                 table3[(num >> 24) & 0xff],
                 table4[(num >> 32) & 0xff],
                 table5[(num >> 40) & 0xff],
                 table6[(num >> 48) & 0xff],
                 table7[num >> 56])

def true_bits_original(num):
    while num:
        temp = num & -num
        num -= temp
        yield temp

funcs = true_bits_original, true_bits_Kelly

import timeit
from itertools import repeat, chain
from random import getrandbits, sample
from collections import deque

# Correctness
for _ in range(1000):
    num = getrandbits(64)
    expect = list(funcs[0](num))
    for func in funcs:
        assert list(func(num)) == expect

# Speed
for _ in range(3):
    nums = [sum(2**i for i in sample(range(64), 24))
            for _ in range(10000)]
    for func in funcs:
        def run():
            gens = map(func, nums)
            consumes = map(deque, gens, repeat(0))
            deque(consumes, 0)
        t = min(timeit.repeat(run, number=1))
        print('%4.1f ms ' % (t * 1e3), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You initial code is already pretty efficient. The thing is **the CPython interpreter make it slow**.

Indeed, the interpreter use *reference-counted variable-sized integers* that are expensive to manage. Thus, `-num` allocates a new integer object as well as `num & ...` and `num -= temp`. This means **3 expensive allocations** are done. The yield is also a quite expensive operation (it cause a low-level context-switch).

Such overhead can be mostly removed by **just-in-time compilers** (JIT). The PyPy general-purpose JIT-based interpreter for example is able to mostly remove the overhead of object allocations (thanks also to a fast garbage collector) though PyPy does not yet optimize the `yield` very well. Alternatively, **Numba** can be used here. Numba is a JIT compiler meant to optimize numerical codes that can be used in code executed by CPython. For example the following code is a bit faster:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(uint64,)')
def true_bits(num):
    while num:
        temp = num & -num
        num -= temp
        yield temp
```

That being said, it is limited to 64-bit integers (or smaller) like Numpy does. **Cython** could also help by compiling the code ahead of time using a basic compiler. This is similar to writing your own C module expect you do not need to write C code and Cython make this process much easier.

If you want to optimize the code further, then you certainly need to **use such tools in the caller function** so not to pay the expensive overhead of *function calls* from the CPython interpreter (which are at least 10 times slower than native ones).

---

If this is not possible (hopeless situation), you can use the following approach with Numba:

```py
@nb.njit('(uint64,uint64[::1])')
def true_bits(num, buffer):
    cur = 0
    buffer.fill(0)
    while num:
        temp = num & -num
        num -= temp
        buffer[cur] = temp
        cur += 1
    return cur

buffer = np.empty(64, dtype=np.uint64)
written_items = true_bits(154781, buffer)
# Result stored in in buffer[:written_items]
```

The idea is to write the result in a *pre-allocated* buffer (since creating Numpy arrays is slow in this context). Then the function writes the value in the buffer when needed and returns the number of written items. You can get the actual items with `buffer[:written_items]` or you can iterate on the array but be aware that doing this is almost as expensive as the computation itself (again due to the CPython interpreter). Still, it is faster than the initial solution.